# Why is it different between entry val and str(same)?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    
    root = Tk()
    root.title("TEST ")
    
    lab_pro_val4=Label(root)
    lab_pro_val4=Label(root,    text="Anything input",    width=30,    height=1 )
    lab_pro_val4.pack()
    
    ent_pro_val4 = Entry(root) 
    ent_pro_val4.pack()
    
    
    def btncmd4_add():
       
       tru = (ent_pro_val4=='TEST123')
       print(tru)
        
    
    btn4_ppid = Button(root, text="Check ", command= btncmd4_add,bg = "white")
    btn4_ppid.pack()
    
    
    root.mainloop()
```

I used Tkinter but I had some trouble.

My question : why is it diff from entry to `str(same)`

I type the 'TEST123' in entry box.

But it's False... Why is it different?

Please let me know.

Comment: `ent_pro_val4` is the Entry object itself.  It is *not* the text contained in the Entry, which you would retrieve via `ent_pro_val4.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

ent_pro_val4 is `Entry` widget, you need to [get value of said widget](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-entry-widget-in-tkinter), which can be done using `.get()`, that is replace

```
tru = (ent_pro_val4=='TEST123')
```

using

```
tru = (ent_pro_val4.get()=='TEST123')
```